# iOS what's the best practice for letting the user know that I'm sending data to the server?

Tags: ios, mobile-application, ux-designer

I have an app that when the user clicks on button, i want to send her/his response to the server, I want to tell the user that that I'm sending now the data to the server.

1. I know that there is a spinner, but where should I put it? (on the top right of the navigation bar? )
2. If not spinner, what's the best user experience for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on why you want users to know information is going to the server, and how you want to affect their behavior.

- **If you're just reassuring them that their information didn't vanish**, you could go ahead with the spinner in the phone's status bar, or a few-pixels-high progress bar like the one used in Messages.

  - The progress bar might be preferred if your uploads can vary a lot in duration (e.g., uploading photos) since it reassures the user that the process has started successfully.
  - It could optionally be followed by an unobtrusive banner or sound notification when the server confirms receipt (but this might be annoying if sending to the server is a very frequent operation).
- **If you need them to wait until their information is received**, then there's no need to be subtle. You can give them a progress bar overlay that actually prevents them from doing anything else in the app until the server confirms receipt. Or, you can distract them by giving them a task that can be done asynchronously (e.g., tagging their recent submission). [This post has some good examples of progress bar, asynchronous activity, and dummy content methods](http://uxmovement.com/mobile/3-tricks-to-make-users-think-your-app-loads-faster/).
- **If you need them to know that the information currently on the screen might be updated** but it's still okay for them to look at the old info, you can leave the screen as it is but provide a more conspicuous progress bar or loading icon, similar to the refresh-on-pulldown throbbers used in Mail and Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

What do your users expect? What do apps similar to yours do? Ideally you would know your users and the apps that they use - this would give you a good place to start.  Then, if you can, make some mock-ups (or prototypes) and ask your users (or your target audience).

Oftentimes you'll find out very quickly which alternative is better.